# NA result in converting string to POSIXct date time in R

Tags: r, datetime, type-conversion, posixct

Uploading csv file and converting a datetime from character to POSIXct I stumbled in a unexpected NA result:

as.POSIXct("20210328 02:00:00", format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")

this seems to happen only for this record...
Any idea why?
Thank you!

Comment: Works fine for me at my end. I am going to guess this is related to Daylight savings in your local timezone. Try `as.POSIXct("20210328 02:00:00", format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S", tz = 'UTC')`

Comment: it works fine! 
Thanks Ronak! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be related to Daylight savings in your local timezone, `as.POSIXct` uses local timezone by default. Try to use timezone as `UTC`.

```
as.POSIXct("20210328 02:00:00", format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S", tz = 'UTC')
#[1] "2021-03-28 02:00:00 UTC"
```

You can also use `lubridate::ymd_hms` which uses UTC timezone by default.

```
lubridate::ymd_hms("20210328 02:00:00")
```